# How to update a deployed application after editing / adding .jsp and .java files?

Tags: deployment, jboss, intellij-idea

I run debug (remote) from IntelliJ IDEA 11.0 on local jboss-portal-2.7.2. IDEA makes application deployment. And the browser opens.

After editing the .jsp files I do "Package file (Ctrl+Shift+F9)" and do the redeployment via:

```
twiddle.bat -s jnp://localhost:1099 -user=admin -password=admin invoke "jboss.system:service=MainDeployer" redeploy "file:C:/Users/Abbas/Projects/my-app/my-portlet/target/my-portlet.war"
```

but it helps only after editing the content which not compile like JavaScript code.

In the case of .java files I have been trying do "Compile (Ctrl+Shift+F9)" and do the redeployment via twiddle.bat but the changes do not take effect.

Now works only restart (Run/Stop, Run/Debug). But I do not want each time to re-deploy all packages.

Comment: It's recommended to perform updates using the built-in methods as described in the documentation: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-a-running-java-ee-application.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Jrebel.

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/